# Windows 8.1 Offline Folder from NAS on home network?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, sync, nas

On my home network I have a NAS device. It's an old IOmega StorCenter iX2 that runs SAMBA. I have it configured with mirrored drives. It's old, but it has served me well.

I have a new Windows 8.1 laptop. Here is what I want to do.

1. On the laptop, set the My Documents folder to point to a shared folder on the NAS
2. Set this folder so Offline Files are enabled so when the laptop is out of my home, the my documents files are still available.

Now, I'm pretty sure this was straightforward in XP, Vista and Windows 7. But, I am stuck in 8.1.

For #1, I can browse to "This PC", then right click on "Documents", select Properties, go the Location tab and then specify the path to my NAS folder. This seems to work fine.

For #2, I'm stuck. When I view the folder I do not see Sync options or Always Available on the ribbon. If I go to Control Panel->Sync Center, the Manage Offline files link doesn't seem to launch anything and "Set up new Sync partnerships" doesn't seem to let me set up sync to the NAS.

Any suggestions? Can I do this in Windows 8.1 or is my thinking to too old fashioned.

I've seen similar questions posted like http://www.networksteve.com/windows/topic.php/NAS_files,_Offline,_Sync_Centre_and_windows_8.1/?TopicId=61609&Posts=4

Answer (score 0):

Right click on network folder, select option Always Available Offline. Work on folder on network location.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for something like called [Work Folders](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20130917/windows-8-1-work-folders-the-free-self-hosted-dropbox-for-enterprise-built-into-windows/). I am not sure if you can set up a host for this using SAMBA.

Kind regards,

Erik